# How to use xargs/find to execute on per file basis

Tags: php, find, xargs

I have some php scrits in a subfolder and want to run some of them (found by a regular expression) via command line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
find . -name email[^T]*\.php -print0 | xargs -0 -t -r /usr/local/bin/php
```

unfortunately only the first php script is executed.

Is there a way to tell xargs to execute the /usr/local/bin/php command on a per file basis?

Regards

Jeremy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `xargs` to only pass a single argument to the command by using `-n 1`.

Or you could just use `-exec ... \;` in find.